# Automatically send SCORM data to LMS

Tags: javascript, scorm

I have this code so far...

```
function sendData() {

    // this work out where I am and construct the 'cmi.core.lesson.location' variable
    computeTime();
    var a = "" + (course.length - 1) + "|";
    for (i = 1; i < course.length; i++) {
        a = a + qbin2hex(course[i].pages).join("") + "|";
            if (iLP == 1) {
                    a = a + course[i].duration + "|";
                    a = a + course[i].timecompleted + "|"
            }
    }
    SetQuizDetails();

    a = a + course[0].quiz_score_running + "|0|0|0|0|0|0|";
    objAPI.LMSSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location", "LP_AT7|" + a);
    bFinishDone = (objAPI.LMSCommit("") == "true");
    objAPI.LMSCommit("");
    console.log("Data Sent!");
}
setTimeout(sendData(), 1000);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as intented. Data should be sent off to the server every 1000ms, but that's not happening. What am I missing here?

As I side note, this is SCORM 1.2.

Comment: You can describe many things as "that's not happening"... it's usually better to describe exactly what **does** happen...

Comment: The data is being created, and it is getting to "`objAPI.LMSCommit("")`", but the data doesn't seem to be ending up on the server. However, the already in-place exit function that includes an extra line to stop the LMS (`objAPI.LMSFinish("")`) does work.

Comment: objAPI.LMSCommit("") should be telling the LMS to store the data.  Possibly trace out if thats "true".  Above appears to do that call 2 times which isn't a show stopper but may increase the SCORM chatter from client to backend.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're calling

```
setTimeout(sendData(), 1000);
```

which is equivalent to

```
var foo = sendData();
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

seeing as `sendData` returns nothing, this becomes equivalent to

```
setTimeout(undefined, 1000);
```

you probably meant:

```
setTimeout(sendData, 1000);
```

Comment: This was from an old snippet. Forgot to take that out.